# Date field in OpenSearch index showing as String in Discover page

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, opensearch

I've got to index a JSON file to OpenSearch through AWS Lambda from a S3 bucket to create several reports out of it. However a field that is supposed to be a date field is showing as if it was String in OpenSearch Discover.

Sample of the json file I'm indexing

*{*

*"@timestamp": "2020-08-25",*
*"map-migrated": "NULL",*
*"prod_backupmonthly": "yes"*

*}*

Lambda code to index json file

```
import re
import urllib
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import json
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection, AWSV4SignerAuth

session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.client('s3')


region = 'Selected region' 
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials, region)

host = 'OpensearchDomain' 
index = 'lambdaIndex'
type = '_doc'
url = host + '/' + index + '/' + type

client = OpenSearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = auth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #Retrieving bucket's name where the file will be dropped
    bucketInput = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    
    #Retrieving dropped file's key (name and prefix)
    keyInput = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding = 'utf-8')
    
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucketInput, Key = keyInput)
    body = response['Body']
    data = json.load(body)

    my_index = 'inventory'
    idNum = 1 

    try:
        response = client.search(
            index = my_index
        )
        print('\nSearch results:')
        print(response)  
    
        response = client.indices.delete(
            index = my_index
        )
        print(response)

        response = client.indices.create(my_index)
        print('\nCreating index:')
        print(response)
        
        
        for line in data:
            id = str(idNum)
            response = client.index(
                index = my_index,
                body = line,
                id = id,
                refresh = True
            ) 
            print(response)
            idNum = idNum + 1
        print('\nAdding document:')
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This doesn't show any errors, but the field @timestamp is simple saved as a String instead of a Date

edit_1: adding result of GET ec2-inventory/_mapping/?pretty=true

```
{
  "ec2-inventory" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        
        "Name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "OS" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "availabilityZone" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "instanceType" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "map-migrated" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "resourceId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[How the field @timestamp appears in Visualize. When added I'm unable to filter or order it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JML0t.png)

Edit_2: Adding screenshot of Discover tab

[Discover tab where @timestamp field is selected and unable to be sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFxl0.png)

Comment: Can you show the mappings for the index? In dev tools you can get it via `GET $yourindex/_mapping/?pretty=true`

Comment: @Riz it threw the following error {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [$yourindex]",
        "index" : "$yourindex",
        "resource.id" : "$yourindex",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [$yourindex]",
    "index" : "$yourindex",
    "resource.id" : "$yourindex",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_"
  },
  "status" : 404
}

Comment: by $yourindex I meant the index you have.

Comment: @Riz My bad. I ran GET $ec2*/_mapping/?pretty=true and got an empty JSON { }

Comment: No no...do you see your data in Dashboards/Kibana? You should see '_index' . Take the value of that fields and do `GET "TheValueYouGetFrom_index"/_mapping/?pretty=true`

Comment: @Riz Okay I finally was able to find the name of the index. I posted the result of the query as an edit to the post and added an image of the field in the visualize tab

Comment: Can you also show the timestamp field in 'discover' where you say you see it as a string and not date?

Comment: @Riz Okat I added the screenshot in a second edit, there you can see the timestamp field is selected and cannot be sorted. Also it is not a String it is a Unknown Field I confused those

Comment: Timefield seems to be alright in your case. You can try to update the mappign for date field for the index and check if it has soem effect. Link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

Comment: @Riz that returns the following error: `"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [text] to [date]"
  },
  "status" : 400`

Comment: @SayonaraChops What was your solution to this problem? I face the same problem.